# Remove (or replace) everything after a specified character in R strings

Tags: r, regex

I have a column of strings that I would like to remove everything after the last '.'

I tried:

```
sub('\\..*', '', x)
```

But my problem is is that for some of the stings there are x2 '.' and for some only x1 '.'
eg

```
ENST00000338167.9
ABCDE.42927.6
```

How can I remove only characters after the last '.'??
So that I'm left with:

```
ENST00000338167
ABCDE.42927
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` to match the `.` (escaped as it is a metacharacter for any character) followed by 0 or more characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]*`) until the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", x)
#[1] "ENST00000338167" "ABCDE.42927"
```

---

Or use `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, "\\.[^.]*$")
#[1] "ENST00000338167" "ABCDE.42927"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("ENST00000338167.9", "ABCDE.42927")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way is by "capturing" the part before.

```
sub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", x)
```